# I want my ViewController to disappear in condition

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

im making a slide-on view controller that connected to didSelectRowAt method but i want it to be called accordint to a condition retrieved from firebase
this is my code and the slide-in ViewController no longer appears whats the problem?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            checkSensors()
            checkAvailability()
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfirmAndPay")
                            
                            if let presentationController = viewController.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController {
                                presentationController.detents = [.medium()] /// change to [.medium(), .large()] for a half and full screen sheet
                            }
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            ref.child("Areas").observeSingleEvent(of:
               .value, with: { (snapshot) in

              let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let isAvailable = value?["isAvailable"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let areaname = value?["areaname"] as? String ?? ""
            
            ref.child("Sensors").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [self] (snapshot) in

              let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
              let Value1 = value?["Value1"] as? Double ?? 0.0
              let Value2 = value?["Value"] as? Double ?? 0.0
            
                if  areaname == "King Saud University" && isAvailable == 1 && Value1 == 1  {
                    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else if areaname == "King Khalid Airport" && isAvailable == 1 && Value2 == 1  {
                    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }else {
                    let cell = self.ParkingsViews.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
                    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                    cell.Alert.text = "No Available Parkings"
                }
            
                
            })})
        }
```

Comment: Maybe everything is going to your `else` block which does not present any view controller. I suggest to put some breakpoints into your if conditions to see if the code is actually going inside the desired `if` condition

Comment: The question isn’t clear. The viewController isn’t appearing, or is it appearing and you want it to disappear?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur its appearing but i want it to appear in a specific condition. the i else a wrote

Comment: @ShawnFrank’s suggestion is the way out then. Use the debugger to figure out which `if-else` statement is executed